# If hashmap only contains one key, is there a way to get that key without knowing anything about it?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashamp with only one key (and a value). Lets say I don't know the key or value of that one key. Is there a way to find it? This may sound dumb but since there is only ONE key, then would there be a way to get that key.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but if you're using the hashmap as a way to hold a pair of values, it would be better practice to use another class like Pair<K,V> from Apache commons to accomplish this.

Comment: You can also use Map.Entry instead of Pair without using a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single key map just do the following:

```
Map<String,String> map = Map.of("A","B");
System.out.println(map.keySet().iterator().next());
```

prints

```
A
```

For a more populated map you can do the following:

You can get the `keySet()` of the map via `map.keySet()` and iterate thru that.

If you want to try and find a particular key associated with a `value` you can
get the `entrySet()` of the map and do something like this:

```
String targetVal = "some value";
for (Entry<String,String> e : map.entrySet()) {
   if (e.getValue().equals(targetVal)) {
      System.out.println(e.getKey());
      // or
      System.out.println(e);

      // keep iterating since multiple keys can
      // map to the same value.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of your keys with `hash_map.keySet()`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-keyset-method-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)s, which enable you to *iterate* over any `Collection` (or `Map`'s `entrySet()`):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("First", "Entry");

        System.out.println(map.entrySet().iterator().next());
    }
}
```

This prints: `First=Entry`, where `First` is the key and `Entry` is the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
hashMapObj.entrySet().iterator().next();
```

is the answer to your question.